# Make Django query with .extra

Tags: django, django-queryset, absolute-value

My aim is to create a query which calculate the absolute value of my field and calculate the average of them as well. I have read about it and I tarted to use the `.extra` possibility in Django but I couldn't achieve my goals. I attach my attempt ant the desired SQl query too. Thank you in advance.

**The desired result would be equeal the reult of this PosreSql query:**

```
SELECT
  time_stamp,
  AVG(ABS(ddt))
FROM tropo
WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN '2018-01-16 8:00' AND '2018-01-17 8:00'
GROUP BY time_stamp
```

**My attempt is in Django:**

```
Table.objects.all().filter(time_stamp__range=(2018-01-16 8:00, 2018-01-17 8:00))
.extra(select={"field_abs": "abs(field)"})
.values('time_stamp')
.annotate(avg_field=Avg('field_abs'))
```

How can I reach that my Djanogo query works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don`t think you really need extra query here, try this:

```
from django.db.models import Func, Avg

tables = Table.objects.filter(time_stamp__range=(2018-01-16 8:00, 2018-01-17 8:00))
tables = tables.values('time_stamp').annotate(avg_field=Avg(Func('field', function='ABS')))
```

Comment: +1 avoiding using extra is extra cool! More about power of `Func` one can find here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/database-functions/ and what can be fired when using `postgresql` is listed here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions.html

Comment: Thank you @Basalex, you suggested answer is worked fine for me. It was very useful for me!